# Not able to read file in scala

Tags: scala

[Link of my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dG3x.png) I am a beginner in Scala, trying to read the file but getting the `java.io.FileNotFoundException`,can someone help.

```
package standardscala

case class TempData(day :Int,doy :Int, month:Int, year :Int, precip :Double, snow :Double, tave :Double, tmax :Double, tmin :Double )

object TempData {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("DATA/MN212.csv")
    val lines = source.getLines().drop(1)  // to get the lines of files,drop(1) to drop the header
    val data= lines.map { line => val p = line.split(",")
      TempData(p(0).toInt,p(1).toInt,p(2).toInt,p(4).toInt,p(5).toDouble,p(6).toDouble,p(7).toDouble,p(8).toDouble,p(9).toDouble)
    }.toArray

    source.close() //Closing the connection

    data.take(5) foreach println
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting `fileNotFound` then the file wasn't found. No big mystery here. It might be a mis-spelling error, but more likely the program is not being executed in the directory that you are assuming when when your code specifies the _relative_ path to the file.

Comment: What folder are you running your program from? If you're on a Unix-like machine, `pwd` will give you this information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **absolute path**, and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Ostensibly yes, this solves the problem. But it also is not a good habit to get into, as it means the code will run on literally no other machines.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to move your csv file into a resources folder and load it as a resource like:

```
val f = new File(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("your/csv/file.csv").getPath)
```

Or you could try loading it from an absolute path!

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this post about reading CSV](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/csv-file-how-to-process-open-read-parse-in-scala) by Alvin Alexander, writer of the Scala Cookbook:

```
object CSVDemo extends App {
  println("Month, Income, Expenses, Profit")
  val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/tmp/finance.csv")
  for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
    val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    // do whatever you want with the columns here
    println(s"${cols(0)}|${cols(1)}|${cols(2)}|${cols(3)}")
  }
  bufferedSource.close
}
```

As Silvio Manolo pointed out, you should not use `fromFile` with absolute path, as you code will require the same file hierarchy to run. In a first draft, this is acceptable so you can move on and test the real job!